# Hindi Voice from Assistant

Tags: python, audio, translation, voice, hindi

I wish to have voice assistant in Hindi. Can `engine.say()` accept translated text? My code is below. It speaks English text, but not Hindi text. No error occurs, however no voice occurs. (My laptop sound=100%).
Can anyone help?

```
import pyttsx3
from translate import Translator  

engine = pyttsx3.init()
  

translator= Translator(from_lang="english",to_lang="hindi")
translation = translator.translate("Today is Tuesday")
print(translation)
engine.say("My first code on text-to-speech")
engine.say(translation)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: which translator library is this?

Comment: Try it with English text first to see if it's at all functional.

Comment: always post a workable copy N paste able code ...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ... if U want us to help you help us by including critical items like your imports

Answer (score 0):

Your code ran fine after I installed its upstream dependencies

```
pip3 install  translate   pyttsx3
```

when I ran it got this error

```
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so then I installed `libespeak1` ... I am on Ubuntu so this command is

```
sudo apt-get install libespeak1
```

then below python code executed correctly and I could hear the translation

```
from translate import Translator

import pyttsx3

translator= Translator(from_lang="english",to_lang="hindi")
# translation = translator.translate("Today is Tuesday")
translation = translator.translate("Today is Tuesday and its the day before Wednesday")
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty("languages",'hi')
engine.say(translation)
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Thanks. However problem not resolved. I am using Windows envt.